# Один Custom валидатор для нескольких элементов управления

Tags: html, asp.net

Есть панельки:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlType1" runat="server">
<td>Недвижимость</td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAff1" runat="server"  OnTextChanged="txtCov_TextChanged"   
 AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox> </td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCov1" runat="server"  OnTextChanged="txtCov_TextChanged"
 AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="CV_Cov1" ControlToValidate="txtCov1" 
 ControlToCompare="txtAff1" Type="Integer"  Operator="LessThan"
ErrorMessage="Ошибка" CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic" Text="*"/>           
</asp:Panel>


<asp:Panel ID="pnlType2" runat="server">
<td>Отделка</td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAff2" runat="server"  OnTextChanged="txtCov_TextChanged" 
  AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCov2" runat="server"  OnTextChanged="txtCov_TextChanged" 
  AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="CV_Cov2" ControlToValidate="txtCov2" 
ControlToCompare="txtAff2" Type="Integer"  Operator="LessThan"
ErrorMessage="Ошибка" CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic" Text="*"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

Валидаторы Compare работает. Они сравнивает 2 текстовые поля.
Эти 2 валидатора работает и выполняет одинаковые условии.
Как сделать один CustomValidator для двух `asp:Panel`, чтобы вызывался один раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Только использовать кастомный валидатор, где нужно будет самому написать логику валидации.

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" OnServerValidate="ServerValidate" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateEvent">
```

Серверный обработчик

```
protected void ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args) {
    int aff, cov;
    bool isValid = true;
    if (!(int.TryParse(txtAff1.Text, out aff) && int.TryParse(txtCov1.Text, out cov) && (aff > cov)))
        isValid = false;
    if(!(int.TryParse(txtAff2.Text, out aff) && int.TryParse(txtCov2.Text, out cov) && (aff > cov)))
        isValid = false;
    args.IsValid = isValid;
}
```

Писал без IDE, поэтому возможны косяки. По аналогии, делается и клиентская валидация.

```
function ValidateEvent(sender, e) {
    var aff1 = document.getElementById('<%=txtAff1.ClientID %>');
    var aff2 = document.getElementById('<%=txtAff2.ClientID %>');
    var cov1 = document.getElementById('<%=txtCov1.ClientID %>');
    var cov2 = document.getElementById('<%=txtCov2.ClientID %>');
    if (+aff1.value > +cov1.value && +aff2.value > +cov2.value)
        e.IsValid = true;
    else
        e.IsValid = false;
}
```